# Match against word in single quotes

Tags: regex, bash, sed

This is a `sed` and RegEx beginner question, but I was not able to answer it myself through googling.

---

**Szenario**

I have got a plain text file like this as the log file of a command:

```
Checking version of 'make' >= 379... succeeded. (382)
Checking version of 'm4' >= 104... succeeded. (104)
Checking version of 'pkg-config' >= 15... succeeded. (25)
Checking version of 'autoreconf' >= 258... succeeded. (268)
Checking version of 'automake' >= 108... ./_autosetup: line 28: type: automake: not found
```

---

**Desired Outcome**

I would like to extract all words within the single quotes, which occur in combination with `not found` at the end of line.

---

**What I Did and the Problem**

Thus, I first `grep` for `not found` and pipe the result to `sed`: (I am using the line of the `not found` later, thus `-n` with `grep`)

```
grep -n "not found" < textfile.log | sed -n 's/.*\(\'.*\'\).*/\1/p'
```

With this I am getting two errors: First, that it reached end of file while searching `'` and second, that the end of file was unexpected.

I also tried

```
grep -n "not found" < textfile.log | sed -n 's/.*[\']\(.*\)[\'].*/\1/p'
```

to only get the word within the single quotes without the quotes. Only getting the same errors.

---

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that line instead:

```
grep -n "not found" < textfile.log | sed -n "s/.*\('.*'\).*/\1/p"
```

You can use double quotes to quote `'` inside the pattern (so you don't have to backquote them.) That expression also includes the quotes. Without the quotes themselves would require using the parentheses inside the quotes:

```
grep -n "not found" < textfile.log | sed -n "s/.*'\(.*\)'.*/\1/p"
```

But I guess you already know that.

Comment: This a case where it appropriate to change the `/` delimiter to e.g. `#` to make it more readable...

Comment: @Fredrik: Strange. I used to thing that to be done when you do regexps in paths separated by `/` themselves to avoid all the backquoting... However, in this case, you'll end up needing the same number of `/`s than `#`s, so why change? Moreover, `#` may be more readable, but `/` is the standard...

Comment: @Diego - in this case you are right, `"s#.*'\(.*\)'.*#\1/p"` doesn't increase the readability (slow day @ work today :-) Disregard my comment!

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about `sed` but the fixed-field format of the file makes it suitable for other approaches as well:

```
$ grep -n "not found" textfile.log | cut -d"'" -f2
automake
```

Note that you don't need to use `<` since `grep` can take a file as input.

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F"'" '/not found/{print $2}' textfile.log 
automake
```

Finally one in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read; do
    if [[ $REPLY == *not\ found* ]]
    then
        set -- "$REPLY"
        IFS="'"; declare -a Array=($*)
        echo ${Array[1]}
    fi
done < textfile.log
```

outputs:

```
automake
```

Comment: I'm using the `<` for `grep` to suppress the output of the filename. It's useless here for me. Thank's for the hint using `awk`.

Comment: @T.K. - grep does not output the filename, only matching lines. Or perhaps you are using a different version than gnu grep...

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "/not found$/ {s/^[^']*'\([^']*\).*/\1/; p}" filename
```